# How to use my own HTML template with make4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, html, make4ht

Here is my LaTeX file `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{Demo}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
1 + 0 & = 1, \label{eq1} \\
1 + 1 & = 2, \label{eq2} \\
e^{i \pi} = -1. \label{eq3}
\end{align}

Equations \( \eqref{eq1} \), \( \eqref{eq2} \) and \( \eqref{eq3} \)
describe eternal truths.

The equation \( e^{i \pi} = -1 \) can also be rewritten as \( e^{i \pi}
+ 1 = 0 \) which is known as Euler's identity.
\end{document}
```

I convert it to HTML like this:

```
$ make4ht foo mathjax
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

Here is the output `foo.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta name='generator' content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> 
<link href='foo.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
<meta name='src' content='foo.tex' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", inlineMath: [ ["\\\(","\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, processEnvironments: true, packages: ['base', 'color', 'ams'] }, loader: { load: ['[tex]/color', '[tex]/ams'] } }; </script> 
 <script id='MathJax-script' async='async' type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'>\begin{align} 1 + 0 &amp; = 1, \label{eq1} \\ 1 + 1 &amp; = 2, \label{eq2} \\ e^{i \pi } = -1. \label{eq3} \end{align}
</p><!-- l. 12 --><p class='noindent'>Equations \( \eqref{eq1} \), \( \eqref{eq2} \) and \( \eqref{eq3} \) describe eternal truths.
</p><!-- l. 15 --><p class='indent'>   The equation \( e^{i \pi } = -1 \) can also be rewritten as \( e^{i \pi } + 1 = 0 \) which is known as Euler’s identity.
</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

So far so good. However, what I want to do is to use my own HTML template that decides the header and footer. I want only the main content to be generated by `make4ht`.

Here is my template `template.html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title> 
  <meta charset='utf-8' /> 
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> 
  <style>
    body {background: gray}
    main {background: white; max-width: 40em; margin: 0 auto; padding: 1em}
  </style>
  <script>window.MathJax = {tex: {tags: "ams"}}</script> 
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js'></script>  
</head>
<body>
<main>

<!-- HTML converted by make4ht goes here -->

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to ask `make4ht` use this template instead of using its own template to generate the output HTML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use configurable hooks that TeX4ht provides for basic HTML configuration. Here is the basic info that is put in the `.log` file when you use the `info` option for `make4ht`:

```
\Configure{DOCTYPE}.........1
\Configure{HTML}............2
\Configure{HEAD}............2
\Configure{@HEAD}...........1
\Configure{BODY}............2
\Configure{TITLE+}..........1
\Configure{TITLE}...........2
\Configure{@TITLE}..........1
\Configure{Preamble}........2

    <DOCTYPE>
    <HTML 1>
      <HEAD 1>
         <TITLE 1>
            <@TITLE>
            <TITLE+>
         <TITLE 2>
         <@HEAD>
      <HEAD 2>
      <BODY 1>
      ......
      <BODY 2>
    <HTML 2>

The \Configure{@HEAD}{...} command is additive, concatenating the
content of all of its appearances.  An empty parameter requests
the cancellation of the earlier contributions.

For instance,

  \Configure{@HEAD}{A}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{B}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{C}

contributes `BC'.

The \Configure{TITLE+} provides the content for the title,
\Configure{TITLE} sets the envelop, and \Configure{@TITLE} acts as a
hook for introducing localized configurations. As is the case for
\Configure{@HEAD}, the contribution of \Configure{@TITLE} is also
additive.

These configurations should be introduced early enough in the
compilation. For instance, in the case of LaTeX, between \Preamble
and \begin{document} of a local configuration file.

           \Preamble
             %%% here %%%
           \begin{document}
             ...
           \EndPreamble


\Configure{@BODY}...........1
\Configure{@/BODY}..........1

   Variants of \Configure{@HEAD} which contribute their content,
   respectively, after <body> and before </body>.
```

So, you will need to use `\Configure{HTML}` to remove attributes from the `<html>` element, `\Configure{TITLE+}` to set your own title, `\Configure{@HEAD}` to insert most of the stuff to the `<head>` element and `\Configure{@BODY}` and `\Configure{@/BODY}` to insert the `<main>` element.

Here is a full `.cfg` file that shows how it can be done:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{@HEAD}{} % remove default content in HTML header
\Configure{@HEAD}{%
\HCode{<meta charset='utf-8' /> \Hnewline
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> \Hnewline
  <style>\Hnewline
    body {background: gray}\Hnewline
    main {background: white; max-width: 40em; margin: 0 auto; padding: 1em}\Hnewline
  </style>\Hnewline
  <script>window.MathJax = {tex: {tags: "ams"}}</script> \Hnewline
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js'></script>  \Hnewline
}}
\Configure{TITLE+}{test}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<main>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{\Hnewline</main>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The first use of `\Configure{@HEAD}{}` just removes the usual stuff that TeX4ht inserts into the header. We insert all your tags in the second invocation of that configuration. Note use of the `\Hnewline` macro, it is used to insert line break in the generated HTML file.

Because `\Configure{@BODY}` and `\Configure{@/BODY}` are used when the document text is already typeset, we need to deal with paragraphs. `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` is used to avoid tag mismatch.

Here is the resulting HTML

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> <title>test</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' />  
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' />  
<style> 
body {background: gray} 
main {background: white; max-width: 40em; margin: 0 auto; padding: 1em} 
</style> 
<script>window.MathJax = {tex: {tags: "ams"}}</script>  
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js'></script>  
</head><body>
   <main> 

<!-- l. 11 --><p class='indent'>   \begin{align} 1 + 0 &amp; = 1, \label{eq1} \\ 1 + 1 &amp; = 2, \label{eq2} \\ e^{i \pi } = -1. \label{eq3} \end{align}
</p><!-- l. 13 --><p class='indent'>   Equations \( \eqref{eq1} \), \( \eqref{eq2} \) and \( \eqref{eq3} \) describe eternal truths.
</p><!-- l. 16 --><p class='indent'>   The equation \( e^{i \pi } = -1 \) can also be rewritten as \( e^{i \pi } + 1 = 0 \) which is known as Euler’s identity.
</p> 
</main> 
</body> 
</html>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Very clear explanation...again salute to you....

Comment: @MadyYuvi thank you :)